# Distance between point and arc in 3D

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I want to compute the distance between an arc and a point in a 3D space. All I found is the distance between a circle and a point [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjlwL2ZwNPQAhXHsxQKHUIIA-4QFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geometrictools.com%2FDocumentation%2FDistanceToCircle3.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHmbHYwGF6lNmaFjEeoNjgV1ZFQwg&sig2=wsDzGYWWrNLeOHOZXuqi5Q&bvm=bv.139782543,d.d24) (which is either wrong, or where I made a mistake, as I get wrong values):

```
P = np.array([1,0,1])
center = np.array([0,0,0])
radius = 1
n2 = np.array([0,0,1])

Delta = P-center
dist_tmp = np.sqrt( (n2*Delta)**2 + (np.abs(np.cross(n2, Delta))-radius)**2 )
dist = np.linalg.norm(dist_tmp)
```

I have a circle in the x-y-plane with origin at x-y-z = 0 and radius = 1. The point of interest is in distance 1 above the circle. The result of the distance from the code is 1.73.. and not 1.

1. What is the right equation for point-circle distance?
2. How can I extend it to point-arc distance?

Comment: How do you know that you "get wrong values"? I.e. please tell us the data you used, the result you got, and the result you expected. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't forget to tell us the data types of `P` and `center` and `radius`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The example/test-input looks as follows. I have a circle in the x-y-plane with origin at x-y-z = 0 and radius = 1. The point of interest is in distance 1 above the circle.

   __ import numpy as np __
    P = np.array([1,0,1]) __
    center = np.array([0,0,0]) __
    radius = 1 __
    n2 = np.array([0,0,1]) __

From which I would expect a distance from the circle of 1 -- the results is 1.73.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information needed for your first question. I have given an answer to that. For your second question, just how is the arc defined? Clearly it is part of the circle, but how do you state which part?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and answer below. As for the arc: I have two additional points as inputs (np.array([x,y,z]) and define the direction by either clockwise or counter-clockwise.

Comment: What is the purpose of those two points? Do you mean the arc lies in the angle formed by the rays from the circle's center to the projections of those two points onto the circle's plane? Or perhaps something simpler: those points are guaranteed to be on the circle, and the arc goes from one of those points to the other, and the "direction" tells us whether to use the smaller or the larger arc?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a bit unclear. It is the latter: Those two points lay exactly on the circle and define the start and end of the arc. Whether to take the smaller or larger circle is determined by the direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several errors in your code. Here is the answer to your first question.

First, you try to implement the dot product of `n2` and `Delta` as `n2*Delta`, but that is not what the multiplication of 2 np arrays does. Use `np.dot()` instead. Next, you try to take the "absolute value" (magnitude) of a vector with `np.abs`, but that latter is for real and complex numbers only. One way to get the vector magnitude is `np.linalg.norm()`. Changing those gives you the proper answer, and you don't need the calculation you used for variable `dist`. So use

```
Delta = P-center
dist = np.sqrt(np.dot(n2, Delta)**2 + (np.linalg.norm(np.cross(n2, Delta))- radius)**2)
```

That gives the proper answer for `dist`, `1.0`.